# MySQL 5.x SUM by ID query help

Tags: mysql

I am working on a new site and I am having problems with a MySQL Query I am working on. Let's say I have a table (testing) such as:

testing:

```
tid  |  number   | cost
1    |  4        | 5.00
1    |  5        | 10.00
1    |  7        | 15.00
2    |  1        | 2.00
2    |  4        | 4.00
2    |  14       | 5.00
3    |  1        | 6.00
4    |  1        | 1.00
```

What I want to do is create a query that would SUM based on tid, so I would see this once my query was run:

```
tid | cost
1   | 30.00
2   | 11.00
3   | 6.00
4   | 1.00
```

Right now all I have is SELECT tid, SUM(COST) FROM testing, but that is no good. I think I need to have some kind nested query. I'd prefer not to do a cheap coding trick and would like to improve my MySQL abilities, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT tid,SUM(cost) AS cost
FROM testing
GROUP BY tid
```

`GROUP BY` allows you to aggregate results on the fields specified.

further info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I was close :)

Comment: yes you were very close! you should accept the answer if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: I just did. I had to wait as there is a time limit before an answer can be marked accepted.